# How do I specify multiple regions with pyautogui?

Tags: python, image-processing, pyautogui

There are four regions on my screen `someButton.png` that may appear in. I would like to specify these 4 regions rather than the entire screen.

I know we can specify single regions like the below example, but the [documentation](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/screenshot.html) doesn't say anything about multiple regions.

```
    import pyautogui
    pyautogui.locateOnScreen('someButton.png', region=(0,0, 300, 400))
```

I've tried adding multiple keyword:

```
pyautogui.locateOnScreen('someButton.png', region=(0,0, 300, 400), region=(0,0, 400, 500))
```

but I get the error `SyntaxError: keyword argument repeated: region`

**How do I specify multiple regions to search for in pyautogui?**

Edit** Update for comments**

The code I'm working with now:

```
def l():
    l = py.locateOnScreen(levelupimage, confidence=0.90)

    regions = {
        "region 1": (476, 268, 736, 320),
        "region 2": (1328, 268, 1591, 320),
        "region 3": (276, 745, 564, 806),
        "region 4": (1130, 745, 1422, 803)
    }

    for region in regions:
        l = py.locateOnScreen('levelup.jpg', region=region)
        if l != None:
            py.click(l)
```

And the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\x\OneDrive\froggy-pirate-master\avoidShips\eventfarm\eventfarm.py", line 201, in <module>
    daily()
  File "c:\Users\x\OneDrive\froggy-pirate-master\avoidShips\eventfarm\eventfarm.py", line 191, in daily
    levelup()
  File "c:\Users\x\OneDrive\froggy-pirate-master\avoidShips\eventfarm\eventfarm.py", line 55, in levelup
    levelup = py.locateOnScreen('levelup.jpg', region=region)
  File "C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pyautogui\__init__.py", line 175, in wrapper
    return wrappedFunction(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pyautogui\__init__.py", line 213, in locateOnScreen
    return pyscreeze.locateOnScreen(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pyscreeze\__init__.py", line 373, in locateOnScreen
    retVal = locate(image, screenshotIm, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pyscreeze\__init__.py", line 353, in locate
    points = tuple(locateAll(needleImage, haystackImage, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pyscreeze\__init__.py", line 207, in _locateAll_opencv
    needleImage = _load_cv2(needleImage, grayscale)
  File "C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pyscreeze\__init__.py", line 170, in _load_cv2
    raise IOError("Failed to read %s because file is missing, "
OSError: Failed to read l.jpg because file is missing, has improper permissions, or is an unsupported or invalid format
```

`l` is being loaded above the function `l = r"C:\Users\x\OneDrive\froggy-pirate-master\avoidShips\eventfarm\l.jpg"`

The file is still there, does passing the region tuples across in a loop change the format of something?

Comment: `if l != None` should be `if l is not None`, or, more simply, `if l` (it's not discouraged to use the short form, when, like here, you can be sure that anything else will evaluate to `True`). As for “does passing the region tuples [...]”: absolutely not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
regions = {
    "region 1": (0, 0, 300, 400),
    "region 2": (300, 0, 300, 400),
    "region 3": (0, 400, 300, 400),
    "region 4": (300, 400, 300, 400)
}
for region_name, region in regions.items():
    rect = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('someButton.png', region=region)
    if rect:
        print(f"found in {region_name} at this (x,y,w,h): {rect}")
```

I had a look at the source code, and since the part that finds an image in a region can be quite slow, linearly with the possible image positions, it's better to call `locateOnScreen` separately for every region (as opposed to calling it once on a region that contains your four regions).

Reading the source code it also seems that, for speed, you should have both `cv2` ([OpenCV](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/)) and `numpy` installed. If you have only one of them, or none, it will fall back to using `pillow`.

Comment: thank you! I understand what you're doing which is great. I've updated the above to show how I'm trying to implement your suggestion and the frankly massive error message I've got off the back of it!

Comment: from your original suggestion I was getting `valueerror: too many values to unpack (expected 2)` I've added the `.items()` method to the for loop and both your comment and my adjusted code in the OP above now have the exact same error message. `OSError: Failed to read l.jpg because file is missing, has improper permissions, or is an unsupported or invalid format`

Comment: oh, sorry for the missing `.items()`, I should have said it's untested code. That's fixed now. As for your error message, I have no idea, sorry :-(

Comment: the error happens [here](https://github.com/asweigart/pyscreeze/blob/master/pyscreeze/__init__.py#L170), following a failed `cv2.imread(img, LOAD_COLOR)`. You could try that separately

Comment: I've had it come up a bunch of times and I've got around it by loading the objects directly which I'm now doing at the start: `l = r"C:\Users\x\OneDrive\froggy-pirate-master\avoidShips\eventfarm\l.jpg"` unsure what's causing it now.

Comment: Fixed it by using the `l` reference rather than the full r path, unsure why that works but it's working! Or it looks like it's looping through 4 regions which is what I needed, thanks Walter!